Matrix Derivative for $tr(WXAX^TW^T)$ with respect to $X$. $W = diag(w)$, $A$ is symmetrical
[EDIT after the discussion] in comments
I want to take the derivative of $\operatorname{tr}(WXAX^TW^T)$ with respect to $X$
here $W$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix, $X$ is an $n\times m$ matrix where $m<n$, $A$ is an $m\times m$ symmetrical matrix.
I know $\partial\operatorname{tr}(XAX^T) / \partial X = 2XA$ (see usage here for example)
See the derivative on $K_k S_k K_k^T$. Admittedly this is a conclusion I memorized....). However what should the result be if I multiply a diagonal matrix $W$ on both ends?

How did you arrive at $\partial (XAX^T)/\partial X = 2XA$?

Maybe try first to consider the map $X\mapsto X X^T$ and use the definition of derivative to obtain the correct derivate. Then it is fairly easy to generalize to the case $WXAX^T W^T$ (the argument is verbatim the same).

No offense, but just adding stuff in bold face does not make things true. One way of seeing that your derivative cannot be correct is by restricting the map to symmetric matrices $X$. Then you claim the derivative maps $C \mapsto 2XAC$, which cannot be true as it is not a symmetric matrix.

hi @SeverinSchraven  thanks for the comments. I added a line where my conclusion is used.  In the linked Wikipedia section you can see that uses the conclusion of $\partial XAX^T / \partial X = 2XA$.  I removed the bold as indeed it's an unnecessary emphasis

I do not see where this is used. Also it is simply not true. Try to use the definition of derivative and you can easily find the correct expression (and you will immediately see how to deal with the more general case).

That Wikipedia article is actually using the following well-known result
$$\frac{\partial\operatorname{tr}(XAX^T)}{\partial X} = 2XA$$
Note the presence of the trace function.

@greg thanks...  With a trace is actually what I truly need and I confused myself. Is there a result for $\partial tr(WXAX^TW^T) / \partial X$? I have edited my original question

@greg I am a bit puzzled by this expression. The function $$ f: \text{Mat}{n\times m}(\mathbb{K}) \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, f(X)=\text{tr}(XAX^T) $$ should have a total derivative $$ \partial f/ \partial X : \text{Mat}{n\times m}(\mathbb{K}) \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, $$ however, $2XA$ is a again a matrix. Is there a trace missing?

Never mind, one interprets it as a gradient and the trace goes away as it is the corresponding scalar product in this setting... time to go to bed.

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\diag#1{\op{diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\tr#1{\op{tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\,\p #3}}
\def\Hess#1#2{\grad{^2 #1}{#2^2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mblock#1{\left[\begin{array}{c|c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\BEmat#1{\begin{bmatrix}#1\end{bmatrix}}
\def\BEvec#1{\begin{Bmatrix}#1\end{Bmatrix}}
\def\mgroup#1{\left\lgroup\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right\rgroup}
\def\mbrace#1{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right\rbrace}
\def\notimplies{\;{\large\not}\!\!\!\!\!\implies}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{blue}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$Rewrite the known gradient as a total differential
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\tr{YAY^T}}Y &= 2YA \qiq d\tr{YAY^T} = \LR{2YA}:dY \qq
}$$
Then make a change of variables from $\,Y\to X\,$ to obtain
$$\eqalign{
Y=\red{WX} &\qiq dY = \green{W\,dX} \\
d\tr{\red{WX}A\red{X^TW^T}}
 &= \LR{2\,\red{WX}A}:\LR{\green{W\,dX}}
 \;=\; \LR{2W^TWXA}:dX \\
\grad{\tr{WXAX^TW^T}}{X} &= 2W^TWXA \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the Frobenius product,
which has the following properties
$$\eqalign{
C:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n C_{ij}B_{ij}
   \;=\; \tr{C^TB} \\
B:B &= \frob{B}^2 \qquad \{ {\sf Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
C:B &= B:C \;=\; B^T:C^T \\
\LR{PQ}:B &= P:\LR{BQ^T} \;=\; Q:\LR{P^TB} \\
}$$

Thanks. It looks like a form of the "chain rule"? $\frac{\partial tr( g(x) A g'(x) ) }{ \partial x} = \frac{ \partial tr( g(x) A g'(x) ) } { \partial g(x) } \cdot \frac{ \partial g(x) }{ \partial x) }$?  Is this generally true?

When $x$ and $g(x)$ are matrices the Chain Rule runs into serious problems, since the gradient of $g$ with respect to $x$ is a fourth-order tensor and the multiplication required by the rule is not the standard matrix product.  So it may be "generally" true, but it is practically unusable.
